# JSON Data from API URL

Tags: powershell-3.0

- Help with power shell :

I have a API URL which contains json data.
When i click the API URL i will be redirected to a Sign in Page and after providing the required sign in data i will get the JSON data (with some data value).

I have tried as below but i am getting the HTML Output (web page script) :(

**$resource = "https://fm.clouddam.microsoft.com/api/entities/query/Definition.Name=='M.Asset'ANDDateTime('CreatedOn')lt2016-03-28?take=0"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $resource**

Can you please correct me and help me.

i have tried with the API key also still i get the same HTML script not the json data.

Code :

$apiKey = "AIzaSyDLbX1aJdVG6NvN6VwYXX1iM76DU6Cdpak"
$resource = "related URL"

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $resource -Header @{ "X-ApiKey" = $apiKey }

Answer (score 0):

Usually API URLs with logins provide API keys which you can link with your application to fetch data without requiring a login everytime.

I would suggest checking if your API provides keys.

Comment: i tried by adding API key but i am getting the same html script please see code added in Question.